# I'm having problems with my ggplot2 theme system

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm having problems with my ggplot2 drawing, I don't know why, I've restarted Rstudio and its theme system can't be restored to the original, which is the default theme

```
library(tidyverse)
chic <- read_csv("./chicago-nmmaps-custom.csv")
ggplot(chic, aes(x = date, y = temp)) + 
  geom_point()
```

Here's the code I ran

[image]

This is what I got when I ran it

Normal should look like this, as shown below

[image]

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please make your question reproducible: add the output of `dput(chic)`  or `dput(head(chic, 100))` to the question so that answers can be tested. How do you know what the graph should look like?

Comment: have you tried running `theme_gray()`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`theme_set`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/theme_get.html) to replace older themes like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) +
  geom_point()
p
```

[image]

```r
old <- theme_set(theme_bw())
p
```

[image]

```r
theme_set(old)
p
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your advice. It has been solved. The problem is in the data type

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that column `date` is not a date object, it's a column of class `"character"`. Coerce to class `"Date"` and the default grey theme is used.

The output of `str` shows the data set columns' classes and `date` is displayed as `chr`, meaning, a column of class `"character"`. R has real dates and times classes and this column must become one. Everything afterwards will be easier, including `ggplot2` code. `ggplot2`'s layers [`scale_*_date` and `scale_*_datetime`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_date.html) even have special date and date/time breaks and labels arguments, respectively.

```r
str(chic)
#> 'data.frame':    5114 obs. of  9 variables:
#>  $ city    : chr  "chic" "chic" "chic" "chic" ...
#>  $ date    : chr  "1987-01-01" "1987-01-02" "1987-01-03" "1987-01-04" ...
#>  $ death   : int  130 150 101 135 126 130 129 109 125 153 ...
#>  $ temp    : num  31.5 33 33 29 32 40 34.5 29 26.5 32.5 ...
#>  $ dewpoint: num  31.5 29.9 27.4 28.6 28.9 ...
#>  $ pm10    : num  27.8 NA 33.7 40.8 NA ...
#>  $ o3      : num  4.03 4.58 3.4 3.94 4.4 ...
#>  $ time    : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#>  $ season  : chr  "winter" "winter" "winter" "winter" ...

library(ggplot2)

chic |>
  dplyr::mutate(date = as.Date(date)) |>
  ggplot(aes(date, temp)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 year", date_labels = "%Y")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much. The problem lies in the data type. I can convert date to as_Date before drawing

Comment: @sjadsqf Yes, that's what the 2nd row fo `str`'s output says. Will edit to make it more clear.